# Best way to have a list of a user tweets up to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, twitter

I'm looking to do a small project on my own time. Take a look a [this twitter account](https://twitter.com/#!/shakespearesong). I find it funny and would like to set up a webapp allowing users to say which song correspond to each tweet. For this, I'm looking for a reliable way to have an up-to-date list of the tweets from this user.

I'm planning on using Ruby on Rails, MongoDB & Heroku for hosting, but for the beginning I'd like to not have to pay anything. My initial plan was to have a rake task that imports all the current tweets, and then have a worker using the twitter streaming API (via [this gem](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream)). But it seems to me that with heroku, I can have only one dyno or one worker for free, not the both.

So I'm looking for ideas to have a relatively up-to-date list of the tweets from this account that is not too heavy performance-wise. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your task is lightweight enough try [Heroku's Scheduler add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler). You can schedule it on 1 day, 1 hour or 10 minute intervals. You are charged for that time like you would be with your own clock process, but this way you don't need a full dyno running for the clock process alone.

Comment: I ended up doing that. Seems the best way to do what I want for the time being